# Program to print all possible groups of a set of numbers after n steps

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I need to write a program that prints out all the possible groups that can be formed from a given user input. The user also specifies the number of steps (k) and at every step, only two elements can be added to form one group.
My first instinct was to use a simple function to calculate the combinations using nCk and then print out all of them. However, it was pointed out to me that the number of possible combinations will be much higher than nCk.
Assume a set of n=5 numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and k=2
step 1: One group is created. out of all the possible combinations assume a group {(1, 2), 3, 4, 5}.
step 2: Here there are many other possibilities. It can either be {(1, 2, 3), 4, 5}
OR {(1, 2), 3, (4, 5)} OR any other combination
How can I calculate the number of ALL such groups possible in the given number of steps? And also print these groups?
EDIT: at every step two elements are added to show the sum. So after step 1, 1+2=3, the set would look like 3,3,4,5. But for clarifying the problem I'm writing it as (1,2) instead of writing the sum.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why it didn't work. Also, please clarify your requirements: you say "at every step, only two elements can be added to form one group", but your example says "{(1, 2, 3), 4, 5}".

Comment: I tried the nCk approach but that didn't work. Also, yes at each stage only two elements are added. So after step one, I'm treating (1,2) as single element.